# Kivy custom animation functions

Tags: python, animation, kivy

Is there a way to combine various built-in functions for animations or even create custom functions?

I like the `in_out_cubic`, `in_out_quad`, `in_out_sine` functions, but I want to make something like `in_cubic_out_sine` and see if it would be ok.

It's also interesting to experiment with other math functions to create various effects.

How can this be done in Kivy?

Comment: in_cubic_out_sine= animation starts as cubic function and ends as sine function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you point out may have several interpretations, so I'm going to show you the different possibilities:

- Use the `in_cubic` animation from p1 to p2 and `out_sine` from p2 to the final point p3.

  ```
  from kivy.animation import Animation
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.button import Button

  class TestApp(App):
      def animate(self, instance):
          animation = Animation(pos=(200, 200), t='in_cubic')
          animation += Animation(pos=(400, 400), t='out_sine')
          animation.start(instance)

      def build(self):
          button = Button(size_hint=(None, None), text='plop',
                          on_press=self.animate)
          return button

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      TestApp().run()
  ```
- Apply in 50% of the advance in_cubic and in the other out_sine, for this we create a new function:

  ```
  from kivy.animation import Animation, AnimationTransition
  from kivy.app import App
  from kivy.uix.button import Button


  def in_cubic_out_sine(progress):
      return AnimationTransition.in_cubic(progress) if progress < 0.5 else AnimationTransition.out_sine(progress)

  class TestApp(App):
      def animate(self, instance):
          animation = Animation(pos=(200, 200), t=in_cubic_out_sine)
          animation.start(instance)

      def build(self):
          button = Button(size_hint=(None, None), text='plop',
                          on_press=self.animate)
          return button

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      TestApp().run()
  ```

---

And in general you can implement your own function, the only thing to keep in mind that progress takes values ​​from 0 to 1:

```
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

from math import cos, sin, pi, exp

def custom_animation(progress):
    return 1 - exp(-progress**2)*cos(progress*pi)**3

class TestApp(App):
    def animate(self, instance):
        animation = Animation(pos=(200, 200), t=custom_animation)
        animation.start(instance)

    def build(self):
        button = Button(size_hint=(None, None), text='plop',
                        on_press=self.animate)
        return button

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: wow! almost what I need!
almost, because I need something like your first example, but 1) with the parameters pos = (200, 200) for the first animation and pos = (400, 400) for the second animation (one-way movement);
2) the whole animation should be smooth,
there should be no jumps in the middle of the animation.

I somehow see a jump in the first example and a very big jump in the second example, I'm testing on Ubuntu. Could you check it on your system?

Comment: ok, but the question with jumping remained.

it turns out I can not use either the first or second examples, if I want the animation to be smooth. I checked it using uniform motion (without "t=..." ) - even in this case I see jump between animations

Comment: I have used animations as in the first example from @eyllanesc, without seeing "jumping". I have seen what might appear as "jumping" when the two animations don't match well. In the plots of the transition functions in the [Animation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.animation.html) documentation, the slope of the line indicates velocity. If the ending velocity of the first animation doesn't match the starting velocity of the second, you can see what might be described as "jumping".